# Managing inheritance in Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance

So, in our database we had a Car model, but there could be different kinds of cars, with different fields and different processes associated to them, so I made some model classes that inherit from that Car, it's something like this:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=300)


class CarA(Car):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=300)


class CarA1(CarA):
    field_a1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)


class CarA2(CarA):
    field_a2 = models.CharField(max_length=300)


class CarB(Car):
    field_b = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Also, there are trips, and each trip has a car associated to them:

```
class Trip(BaseModel):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

If I have a CarA1 instance, `car_a1`, I can save it in a Trip with `car_a1.car_ptr`, but it would be saved as a Car, and from there I don't think there's a way to get the CarA1 instance again except searching by the Car id in all the subclasses.

So, if I want to know which kind of car the trip has, or get a specific subclass field, it would be really complicated.

What do you suggest to do? I can just keep only the Car class with the specific fields nullable (field_a, field_b, etc), and a field to specify the kind of car, but that doesn't seem right, I would have to check on the kind to validate the fields, etc. But right now it seems like the better solution.

I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6 btw.

Sorry I didn't use real code, I thought it would be way more complicated, also sorry if I didn't explain it very well, I'm sleep deprived and stressed.

Thanks!

Comment: Is fields represent same kind of data ?

Comment: No, in my project some of them are foreign keys, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you **can** get to the child model from the parent model (see [model based inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)).

If you want to stick with your inheritance based design, you could define a field in `Car` called `car_type` which would correspond to the type of the child table. For example:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    CAR_A = 'car_a'
    CAR_B = 'car_b'
    CAR_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (CAR_A, 'Car_A'),
        (CAR_B, 'Car_b'),
    )
    field = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CAR_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

And then you could override the save method of the child models so that their `car_type` field is the one that corresponds to their model.

```
class CarA(Car):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.car_type = Car.CAR_A
        super(CarA, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

# ... similarly for CarB
```

Now you can get to the child model from `Car` based on its `car_type`.

```
if car.car_type === Car.CAR_A:
    print(car.cara.field_a)
```

Note that this will start to get cumbersome if you have many levels of inheritance, so I would encourage you to reconsider your design.

Comment: Thanks! I'm already reconsidering the design, it's part of the reason I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your model is when a new type of car introduced say car c you need to create another table for that. It is not ideal and what you need is one table for store the car details(commonly used) and separate table say Properties to store other details and give a foreign-key relation to Car model.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. In my code some kinds of cars have a foreign key to a user, and others have a foreign to a department. How would those tables be? And also I need to store a car in a trip, would I still store a Car?

Comment: Add two attributes user and dept. and allow black and null true. If there is user then add it or leave it blank. I can't say a fine-tuned model without knowing the full model structure.

Comment: I just checked and there would be 3 nullable fields on the Car model (some of them are actually required depending on the type of the car), do you still think it's a good idea? I think it's better to use separate tables for the fields, like you said, but I'm still not sure how to do it.